# angularjs anchor in iterator (anchorscroll, ng-repeat,loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs

for example,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <p>item.title</p>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   <p>item.up</p>
</div>
```

As i know ,anchor scroll need to specify an id for the anchor, but how can i do the anchor scroll without id, The situation is there's another loop wrap this item repeat. and i can't specify an id like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <p id="anchor{{$index}}">item.title</p>
    ...
    ...
    ...
   <p>item.up</p>
</div>
```

So if the code is like below, there will be multi id="anchor{{$index}}"

```
 <div ng-repeat="parent in parents">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
       <p id="anchor{{$index}}">item.title</p>
      ........
    </div>
</div>
```

And i don't want to use two indexs to specify the id, or the code will be too complex.

How can i solve it .....Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact scenario, I would say that you are going to have to artificially create some kind of unique `anchorId` on the elements you care about.

Again, I don't know what your controller or model look like, but you could use a technique similar to this.

```
angular.forEach(this.parents, function(parent, i){
    //Add unique anchorId to parent
    parent.anchorId = "anchor-" + i;
    angular.forEach(parent.children, function(child, j){

       //Add anchorId to child as well
       child.anchorId = "anchor-" + i + "-" + j;
    });
});
```

This will basically give you something you can bind to in the DOM and then trigger a scroll with a click event. The bindings would be similar to what you have above.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parent in ctrl.parents">
   <h1 id="{{parent.anchorId}}">{{parent.name}}</h1>
   <div data-ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
      <h2 id="{{child.anchorId}}" class="child">
         {{child.name}}
         <small>
            <a href="" ng-click="ctrl.scrollTo(parent.anchorId)">
             | to {{parent.name}}
            </a>
         </small>
      </h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

And finally in your controller you could create a `scrollTo` method that looked something like this.

```
Ctrl.prototype.scrollTo = function(anchorId){
  this.$location.hash(anchorId);
  this.$anchorScroll();
};
```

This will basically do what you want and allow you to scroll around to your hearts content.

I've wrapped all this up in a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/AfK23/) so you can see the full working example.

Comment: Hi Josh, so as you say, we had to use these two index to specify the id ? And no other solution?

Comment: @Awakening - I'm not saying there is no other way. Just that you need some unique way to identify an element. This is just one possible way to achieve that.

Comment: Hi,Josh, have you met this issue, that i'm using the ng-view, for example http://localhost:8000/main.html#/events, as you see, the /events is the routing, and when i $anchorscorll() the id, the url will like "http://localhost:8000/main.html#/events#anchorId-0-3-2", sometime my page will reload ( it means re-do the routing ), how to prevent this, i just want to anchor scroll, reload is too stupid

Comment: @Awakening - If you want to scroll to an id without changing the route, then you should just use a plain `<a href="#anchor01">` and skip the `$anchorScroll()` call altogether.